# ZAP Form based authentication does not replace username password

Tags: owasp, zap

When I configure ZAP as in the guideline https://github.com/zaproxy/zap-core-help/wiki/HelpStartConceptsAuthentication
the username and password are not replaced with the ones defined in the Users context setting.
Any idea why this happens?
This is same issue as in https://github.com/zaproxy/zaproxy/issues/2079.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at https://github.com/zaproxy/zaproxy/wiki/FAQformauth particularly the 'Diagnosing problems' section.

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, that didn't help much. I have provided feedback to your comment in Github https://github.com/zaproxy/zaproxy/issues/2079